# Set Python's default numerical representation to "Decimal"

Tags: python, decimal

I am doing scientific calculations with both very small and large numbers, so obviously if I'm using python the `decimal.Decimal()` representation is key. The problem is the tedium. Having to type `Decimal()` around every relevant operation is cumbersome.

Is there a way to set the default numeric representation as `Decimal` somewhere, anywhere?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tokenize.html#examples

Comment: Hey Chrisz, thanks for your suggestion. It seems when I try to run exec() it returns None, and I do not know the reason. I have found a different practical solution using the mpmath package.

Answer (score 1):

No, although you can alias the module to a shorter name:

```
In [1]: from decimal import Decimal as d

In [2]: d(10)
Out[2]: Decimal('10')
```

Comment: Yeah, I do appreciate it, but I did read the python documentation and already used 'D=Decimal.' I'm surprised there isn't even some work around to be able to declare data types in python.

Comment: @Φίλλιπ the built in double type is good enough for 99.99% of all needs. I'm sure that extending the language that way wouldn't be worth it for the few people that would find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The use of floats is hardcoded all over the place, and many numeric routines literally can't operate on anything else, particularly stuff written in C.